# Scan image and detect the text android

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, ocr, image-scanner

I want to scan a image to detect the colour and text from the image. I have found OCR [tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) to do the same and implement it. But I don't want to capture image just want to scan image and detect text. Is there any library with which I can detect the text and colour from image when I scan ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at [google's Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). It has said feature and is fairly easy to use.